# Can we burninate the [nutritional-deficiency] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Can we burninate the [nutritional-deficiency](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutritional-deficiency) tag?

The [nutrition](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition) tag is shorter and more broadly applicable. Since the nutrition tag is already about meeting nutrient requirements, nutritional deficiency is only a symptom of failing to meet nutritional requirements, not a separate subject in itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think we should keep that tag, because people are more likely to type in "deficiency" than "nutrition" when they are asking specifically about... nutritional deficiencies. If anything we should probably ditch [nutrition](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition) which is too broad...